# MySQL SELECT query with alias not working in MySQL 5.7.28

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

I have the following MySQL table and query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13a3c84/2

As you can see this is running with `MySQL 5.6`.

I want to execute the following query: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY year DESC) x GROUP BY title;`

This makes the following:

1. Order all rows by year DESC.
2. GROUP BY title will take the first row.

Output with `MySQL 5.6` is:

```
3   Test Name   2017
```

Doing the same with `MySQL 5.7.28`, gives me the following output:

```
1   Test Name   2015
```

I guess, there has something changed between `MySQL 5.6` and `MySQL 5.7.28`, but what?

Comment: There are no aggregate functions in your query so you should not be using group by,

Comment: *as expected* why?

Comment: @P.Salmon There're normally more rows. This is just for testing purposes.

Comment: My comment stands.. and do read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @forpas I was using `MySQL 5.6` for a long time. Now, I upgraded to `MySQL 5.7.28` and this problem occurred.

Comment: @P.Salmon Sorry, what do you mean? Wait … I'll update my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @David there is nothing expected in your code. The logic of your query is wrong. An ORDER BY clause inside a subquery (without a LIMIT) is useless. Also SELCT * with GROUP BY without aggregation will return unpredictable results.

Comment: @forpas What is the right way to output only the row with the highest `year` where `title` is the same?

Comment: Post sample data, not only 2 rows with the same title and expected results and you will get answers.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql 5.7 was the first to by default reject this sort of query.  You will have had to set your sql mode for this query to even run.

When grouping by something everything in the select should be in the group or use an aggregate function.

Your query here is ambiguous therefore can change. If you wanted to select the lowest year use `select title, min(year)`

Title is fine as it's in the group by. And year is fine as it's within an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

You're now getting different results because your query is not fully correct in the first place.

The `GROUP BY` clause allows to merge values from different source rows into a single result set row. There're two ways to accomplish it:

- Perform a calculation that produces a single value, such as `SUM()`, `COUNT()` or `AVG()`.
- Choose rows where a given column has always the same value and select such value.

Your query is and has always been incorrect because it takes a third approach: choose rows where a given column has different values and select one of the values arbitrarily, following no rules to make it deterministic.

Most other DBMSs will just abort the query and throw an error. MySQL, however, has traditionally been very tolerant and just produce incorrect results happily.

Answer (score 0):

*What is the right way to output only the row with the highest year where title is the same?*

You can use the below query to get the desired result.

**Query:**

```
select 
    t1.*
from
    test as t1
        left join
    test as t2 ON t1.title = t2.title and t1.year < t2.year
where
    t2.id is null;
```

**Output:**

> ```
> id | title     | year
> -: | :-------- | ---:
>  3 | Test Name | 2017
>  4 | Test      | 2016
> ```

**Fiddle:**

<kbd>[fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=48ee8331290d590110a088093eacf91a)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

And in MySQL 8+ (using the default settings), you will get an error because you have columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  This, by the way, is the correct behavior.  Your query is malformed.

If you want to select the most recent row of data for each `title`, then you should be thinking "filter" not "aggregate".

That means that you want a `where` clause (or something similar).  For your problem, I recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from test t
where t.year = (select max(t2.year)
                from test t2
                where t2.title = t.title
               );
```

With an index on `test(title, year)`, this should also be faster than your version.

I don't have the two versions on hand to see if what you say is reproducible.  If it is, the reason probably has to do with the materialization of the subquery results.  Throughout the different releases of MySQL 5.7, the optimizer improved.

In order for your version to "work" (I put that in quotes because the syntax is not valid SQL due to the inclusion of non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT`), MySQL has to materialize the subquery.  However, at some point the optimizer may have decided that is not necessary -- basically ignoring the `ORDER BY` in the subquery.  That would explain the difference in the results.

In any case, write the query correctly and this is a non-issue.